# change images on button click using javascript in php page

Tags: javascript

I have stored all images in a folder.
and added an image in div and button "Next" in my php page, but
now i am writing javascript to change the image on click of button "Next".
Please tell me how can i do so?

Comment: You need to show us some code. Tell us what you've tried. We're not here to write code for you, but we're happy to answer specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is storing images urls in js array, then on click event changing the `src` attribute of Your `img` container(by reading next array item) which is supposed to display images. This is it, You can also use `onload` event and show some loader while browser would be downloading image from server.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your html like

`...`

`<div id="img-div">`

`<img ...../>`

`</div>`

`....`

And you need to make an ajax call that sends a number or name of the next image to be taken.

The php page corresponding to the ajax call need to echo the the  tag with the new image in it.

And then you need to replace the  contents using .html() or .innerHTML with js.